# Github: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access

Tags: git, github-actions

Recently I changed to a new computer and faced this "warning message" when pushing to my own `main` branch with a simple protection rule.

The protection rule is:

[image]

and I am facing this warning message below:

```
remote: Bypassed rule violations for refs/heads/main:
remote: 
remote: - At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
```

when pushing to my `main` branch. I wonder if it is a cause of concern? Since I am the owner, I thought this message won't appear.

Comment: You may be the owner, but you're not making the change through the PR process.

Comment: Is the fact that you're using a new computer relevant? Or would this exact same scenario occur on your old computer with that same protection rule?

Comment: @TTT I did not observe this prior to the migration to the new com. I am worried if there's implications.

Comment: @ilovewt if you believe the two computers would act differently, then that points to a difference in authentication. Different token perhaps? Maybe one token has permission (or is for a user that has permission) to bypass the rule and the other doesn't?

Comment: @ilovewt You are not alone. There may be nothing wrong with your computers at all. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/51047#discussioncomment-5437811

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a cause for concern. See the article: [Info messages for bypassing branch protections in Git](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-29-info-messages-for-bypassing-branch-protections-in-git/), published to the GitHub Blog March 29 2023.

*"We now show bypassed branch protection rules in response to Git pushes. These are information messages and are not designed to block workflows.
Historically there was no indication after a Git push that branch rules had been bypassed.
Repo admins, actors with the bypass branch protections permissions, and actors in bypass lists on branch protections will now see a list of rules that were bypassed."*

It's nothing to do with the fact that you're using a new computer, just that the move coincided with an update to GitHub's rule bypass visibility.

Comment: i've been using git since the new policy, but only now (June) that I get this message. Why is that?

Comment: what is the way around